# Clicking radio buttons with label twice Knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have list of radio item which I am displaying like this

```
<!-- ko if: $data.children -->
<li data-bind="attr: { id: id}" class="has-children">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="massType" data-bind="value: id, checked: $root.massTypeSelectionForOrderList"/>
        <span class="text" data-bind="text:name"> </span>
    </label>
    <ul class="child" data-bind="template: { name: 'treeLarge1', foreach: children }"></ul>
</li>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko ifnot: $data.children -->
<li data-bind="attr: { id: id}">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="massType" data-bind="value: id, checked: $root.massTypeSelectionForOrderList">
        <span class="text" data-bind="text:name"> </span>
    </label>
</li>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The issue is that I have to click the radio button / label twice for the radio button to be selected. I have tried removing the value binding but it doesn't work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using a old version of Knockout?

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like the problem lies in the code you posted here. I put together this snippet based on your code, and the radio buttons behave as expected. You can use this snippet as a starting point to try to replicate your problem.

```js
vm = {
  id: '1',
  massTypeSelectionForOrderList: ko.observable(false),
  name: 'One',
  children: [{
    id: '2',
    massTypeSelectionForOrderList: ko.observable(false),
    name: 'Two'
  }]
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<template id='treeLarge1'>
  <!-- ko if: $data.children -->
  <li data-bind="attr: { id: id}" class="has-children">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="massType" data-bind="value: id, checked: $root.massTypeSelectionForOrderList" />
      <span class="text" data-bind="text:name"> </span>
    </label>
    <ul class="child" data-bind="template: { name: 'treeLarge1', foreach: children }"></ul>
  </li>
  <!-- /ko -->

  <!-- ko ifnot: $data.children -->
  <li data-bind="attr: { id: id}">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="massType" data-bind="value: id, checked: $root.massTypeSelectionForOrderList">
      <span class="text" data-bind="text:name"> </span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <!-- /ko -->
</template>
<ul data-bind="template: 'treeLarge1'"></ul>
```